# Changed AppDelegate name causing app update to crash?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I've updated my Xcode project (created a new project and copied the source files over to the new one) such that the AppDelegate now has a new name. I noticed if I build this new version over the old one on my iPhone I get the following error `Unknown class OLD APP DELEGATE NAME in Interface Builder file`. However when I delete the app from my iPhone and reinstall a fresh copy everything works fine. Does this mean that users who install my update will crash and will have to delete the app losing all their data, or is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: This is difficult to explain. Are you sure that after the first crash your app continue to crash each time you launch it? Couldn't it be a matter of the app being "in background" when you installed it from Xcode?

Comment: I just tried reinstalling my app from the app store, and I removed I form background then reinstalled from Xcode, but I get the same error...

Answer (score 4):

When you rename your UIApplicationDelegate subclass, you must be sure to also update it in the main nib file (the one named by `NSMainNibFile` key in your Info.plist). This is usually `MainWindow.xib` and/or `MainWindow-iPad.xib`.